# json parse error in ajax return with an html comment

Tags: php, json, ajax, parse-error

The attached image shows what is coming back from an ajax call to a PHP script.  The script builds the simple array that you see, and for some reason it adds the html comment before the array.

[image]

```
<!-- translation function -->
```

No idea where this is coming from, or what it is for. I'm just wondering what this is and if anyone has ever seen it before.  It is causing a json parse error, unexpected token <

Thanks!

Comment: Have you searched your source codes for the "translation function" string?

Comment: I did a global search of my codebase with no luck.  Best guess is that it's being generated dynamically.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what it is and searched for it on Google, found no sensible results. So it is probably something related to your project or some tool that it uses. While you do not know the exact source yet, you can remove the comment of a JSON using a function like this:

```js
function stripHTMLComments(json) {
    let parts = json.split('<!--');
    for (let index = 0; index < parts.length; index++) {
        if (parts[index].indexOf('-->') >= 0) parts[index] = parts[index].substring(parts[index].indexOf('-->') + 3)
    }
    return parts.join("");
}

console.log(stripHTMLComments("<!-- foobar -->{'a': 1, 'b': 2}"));
```

Comment: Isn't it better to solve the original problem? This time it's a comment, what will it be next time? Somehow you always have to get the output of your PHP scripts under control.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware this is not a matter of choice. The function I have given was not meant to be used instead of solving the problem. It was meant to be a temporary fix while the problem is being solved. It is quite often that you need to have a quick fix to make sure that the service is working. Once the service is working you have the possibility to remove the temporary solution and solve the original problem. So this answer was not meant to avoid solving the issue.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware With the "While you do not know the exact source yet, you can remove the comment of a JSON using a function like this" sentence I tried to make it clear that the original problem needs to be resolved. If my answer is still confusing, then I would like to kindly ask you for the quote that would mislead future readers of this answer. Thanks!

Comment: I agree a temporary solution can be handy, and yours certainly is. Thanks for the clarification. Btw, I didn't downvote your answer, downvoters rarely make their presence known.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I was grateful to see a comment by a down-voter and to be able to discuss it. It turns out it was not the case. Never mind, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @LajosArpad thank you for the workaround.  I will utilize this and keep researching.  Another interesting observation is that it doesn't happen all the time.  Out of the blue it will just return clean with no comment. Thanks!

Comment: @midasxl happy to help. If it is not putting that into the response all the time, then it is also a helpful information. You might look into which requests are putting that comment into the response and try to find out where they are in the code and how they are building up the response.